# Page-specific headers and footers

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, report

For my thesis I currently use `MiKTeX` and the `report` class in order to fulfill the needs of my university, and they also demand page specific headers and footers. This should be achieved by using the `fancyhdr` package.

What I want is a right-aligned page number in the footer, together with a blank header, and that for each page, except for the

- title page, and the
- affidavit.

Those just have to be blank. I know that page numbers are centered by default for new chapter pages, but that's not what I need. Roman and arabic page numbering should be taken into account of course.

PS: I've read that `fancyhdr` and the `geometry` package (which I also currently use) don't go well together. Should I therefore use an alternative to the `fancyhdr` package?

Comment: You can usr scrlayer-scrpage or titleps instead, but the claim is wrong. Fancyhdr and geometry work fine together. You just have to load geometry first. Where did you read that?

Comment: You don't NEED to use fancyhdr, it is just easier.  Sigh, I suppose you want me to make you an MWE as well.

Comment: For you the matter might seem straightforward, but I struggle with the correct implementation of the page specific headers and footers. No one asked for an MWE, but since you already put effort in your answer, I thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\chapter` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`, you can redefine the plain pagestyle.

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfill\thepage}% page number on right
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
Some text here.
\end{document}
```

---

No page number.

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain=\ps@empty
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
Some text here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your answer in mind, how would someone suppress the page numbering for specific pages, as initially asked. Also what if I want to add a horizontal line? This solution also doesn't consider pages beside those with chapters on it, the page number still gets centered.

Comment: Ah, so you want a totally blank plain pagestyle.  Come to think of it, `\let\ps@plain=\ps@empty` would be simpler.

Comment: If you want a line below the header, use fancyhdr and \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{}}